# Using Angular populate() I cannot access the data in the populated field

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, object

I'm using an ObjectId reference for a collection to another collection and the populate() method is working ok.

I cannot access the data in the populated field.

The data is held in an object under the staff field in $scope.detail (see below for $scope.detail).

```
Resource {$promise: Promise, $resolved: false, toJSON: function, $get: function, $save: function…}
$promise: Promise
$resolved: true
__v: 0
_id: "5547bcb05fcea7c532f5c792"
address_1: "21 Carlaw Avenue East"
appointment_date: "2015-05-16T21:30:30.161Z"
city: "East York"
email: "Stephen@graham.com"
jobDone: false
lat: 43.684783
lng: -79.34968479999999
name: "Stephen Graham"
phone: "4163185175"
postcode: "M4K 3M1"
staff: Array[1]
0: Object
  __v: 0
  _id: "552da3ce456c60e5367dbab3"
  email: "lrm@email.con"
  jobs: null
  name: "lrms"
  phone: 12334213123
  signup_date: "2015-04-14T23:33:34.946Z"
  total_paid: 0
  __proto__: Object
  length: 1
  __proto__: Array[0]
total_charge: 25
total_time: 1
```

When I try `$scope.detail.staff.name` - I get undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$scope.detail.staff` is an array, so it needs to be accessed using an array index. Try `$scope.detail.staff[0].name`.

There is more information on JavaScript arrays at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Answer (score 1):

As `staff` is collection, you could do access it by index.

You should do `$scope.detail.staff[0].name` where will give you `"lrms"` as output.

[**Json Array**](https://www.json.com/json-array)

Comment: @Mobaz could I know whats wrong with mine answer..to be mark as correct..as I gave first?